# 500 Error, Works good after first refresh WebSphere, IHS

Tags: websphere, http-status-code-500, f5, ibmhttpserver

External User -> Virtual IP F5 -> IHS (SSL configured)-> WAS 855

there is firewall between IHS and WAS,

When I hit the application URL for the 1st time it gives 500 error, when I refresh the page, It is working good.

I tried to use fiddler, it just says "No server responce" for the 500 error.

In the webserver logs I see only 304 and 302 errors.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: And what WAS logs are saying? Very unlikely that firewall will give you 500 error.

Comment: The http_plugin.log would reflect an error related to the firewall between IHS and WAS. If the WAS Plugin can't forward a request, it will result in a 500 error

Comment: When there is following message. 
This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address https://**********.com is correct.

•Look for the page with your search engine.

•Refresh the page in a few minutes



There is nothing in the Webserver or Plugin log, 
the request isnt reaching Webserver as well..
THis is occouring randomly when navigating thru application as well. Refresh the page and we are good.

Comment: the issue is resolved after network team made some rule changes.